# How to have search parameters in the middle of a path in NextJS?

Tags: url, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to create a page where the user selects a form and is then routed to the correct form page

I have the current folder structure:

`patients/[patientId]/forms/type1/[type1Code]`

`patients/[patientId]/forms/type2/[type2Code]`

Under both type1 and type2 I have a layout containing a Select-component where the user get all the options for the different forms.

This select component does the following onChange:

```
  const handleOnChange = (value: string) => {
    if (!formCodeId) {
      return router.push(`${path}?${searchParams.toString()}/${value}`);
    }
    router.push(value);
  };
```

When I select a form it routes to `patients/[patientId]/forms/type1?param1=123/123code` but it doesn't seem to hit the page.tsx inside the [type1Code] folder. Why is this? Is it invalid syntax to have search parameters in the middle of a url path?
Or do you need to tell NextJS of this somehow?

Comment: Why do you need search parameters in the middle of your url path like this?

Comment: From my `patients/[patientId]` page I have a button pr element of type1 that routes to forms/type2.

To fill in a form of type2 you need certain values from the objects of type2, like its id etc. So I was thinking I could just pass these values as search params before the user selects the form they want. E.g: `patients/[patientId]/forms/type2?type1Id=123`. When they select a form i was thinking i could just append the formCode at the end of the url. E.g `patients/[patientId]/forms/type2?type1Id=123/123-form-code`

Comment: It works if i just put the searchParams at the end. I was just wondering why it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt what you are trying to achieve will be supported by any framework, let alone Next.JS.

In a URL anything after the first question mark is considered the query string. So essentially you URL

patients/[patientId]/forms/type1?**param1=123/123code**

matches `patients/[patientId]/forms/type1` and rest of the URL data would be available in query params.

Here is what the RFC says:

> The query component is indicated by the first question
> mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
> or by the end of the URI.

[Link to RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)

Comment: Aa so its against the RFC. I couldn't find the exact part that specified it. But thanks, I'll not do that then hah